FastAPI - Websockets to multiple Angular Frontends so each frontend detect backend changes made by others
I followed this tutorial for establishing a websocket connection between python 3.8 Fast API Backend and Angular.
https://github.com/lynnkwong/websocket-fastapi-angular
Works fine so far, but what I want to achieve is that multiple clients get the changes made on the back end.
In the case provided, if you open the client from another browser, there will be a new websocket created so both frontends will not detect a change may by the other angular client, but only its own.
The question is is there a way to create such a websocket , that every front end connected client be able to detect changes made from the other clients?
I post the code from the tutorial here :
main.py in Python
import asyncio
import logging
from datetime import datetime

from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("FastAPI app")

app = FastAPI()


async def heavy_data_processing(data: dict):
    """Some (fake) heavy data processing logic."""
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    message_processed = data.get("message", "").upper()
    return message_processed


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    # Accept the connection from a client.
    await websocket.accept()

    while True:
        try:
            # Receive the JSON data sent by a client.
            data = await websocket.receive_json()
            # Some (fake) heavey data processing logic.
            message_processed = await heavy_data_processing(data)
            # Send JSON data to the client.
            await websocket.send_json(
                {
                    "message": message_processed,
                    "time": datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                }
            )
        except WebSocketDisconnect:
            logger.info("The connection is closed.")
            break 

Angular code :
App component.html :
<h2>Send a message to the server:</h2>

<form (ngSubmit)="sendMessage(message); message = ''">
    <input [(ngModel)]="message" name="message" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    <button type="submit" style="margin-left: 10px;">Send</button>
</form>

<h2>Received messages from the server:</h2>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let data of webSocketService.receivedData">
        {{ data.time }}: {{ data.message }}
    </li>
</ul>

app.component.ts :
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketService } from './websocket.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    message = '';

    constructor(public webSocketService: WebSocketService) {
        this.webSocketService.connect();
    }

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.webSocketService.sendMessage(message);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.webSocketService.close();
    }
}

websocket-service.ts :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

interface MessageData {
    message: string;
    time?: string;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WebSocketService {
    private socket$!: WebSocketSubject<any>;
    public receivedData: MessageData[] = [];

    public connect(): void {
        if (!this.socket$ || this.socket$.closed) {
            this.socket$ = webSocket(environment.webSocketUrl);
    
            this.socket$.subscribe((data: MessageData) => {
                this.receivedData.push(data);
            });
        }
    }

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.socket$.next({ message });
    }

    close() {
        this.socket$.complete();
    }
}


Does this answer your question?

to do that you need to change the server part. when receiving a message, you have to save it in database and all ws server have to read the database and send the message.

Thanks Kaperto, but if client B init the change, the backend saves it, how client A will get the change if it has a different socket?

Hi Cris, Yes this solved it. The solution if anyone runs into this is to create a List of existing websockets and then send the message to all of them. This could work well for user groups so send message to users with socket from specific group. Its really flexible to play with. Thanks
